# Difficulty implementing server side session storage using redis and flask

Tags: python, ajax, session, flask, redis

I have a setup where a node.js app is making ajax requests to a flask based python server.  Since ajax requests lack cookie data, I can't use the simple flask session object to persist data across requests. To remedy this, I'd like to implement a redis based server side implementation of a session storage system, but the solutions I've found so far do not work.

One solution I've tried is the following [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/) snippet.
But this doesn't work.  Is there more setup I need to do to configure redis beyond what is mentioned in the quickstart guide? Here is my attempt:

```
...
from flask import session
# Snippet code is copy pasted here verbatum
import session_interface
...   
app = Flask(__name__)
app.session_interface = session_interface.RedisSessionInterface()
...
# Can't access this as session['key'] across requests
session['key'] = value
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '123456789012345678901234'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Another solution I've tried is importing the Flask-Session  [extention](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/).
However, I can't get this to work either. The section I'm confused about is the following:

"We are not supplying something like SESSION_REDIS_HOST and SESSION_REDIS_PORT, if you want to use the RedisSessionInterface, you should configure SESSION_REDIS to your own redis.Redis instance. This gives you more flexibility, like maybe you want to use the same redis.Redis instance for cache purpose too, then you do not need to keep two redis.Redis instance in the same process."

What is meant by this section and how would I have figured this out?  Here is my attempt to make this extension work:

```
...
from flask import session
from flask_session import Session
import redis
...
app = Flask(__name__)
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)
...
# Can't access this as session['key'] across requests
session['key'] = value
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '123456789012345678901234'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Has anyone successfully implemented manual session storage on a server running flask?  Are there other options for getting this functionality?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 13):

I think that's because you missed the URL configuration for your storage Redis, to check that, you can use Redis-CLI to see if there is anything being inserted into Redis.

I use this code and it worked:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_session import Session
import redis
……

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'

app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url('127.0.0.1:6379')

sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
def getSession():
    return session.get('key', 'not set')
def setSession():
    session.set('key')=123
    return 'ok'
……
```

Comment: This code is not wornking, "session" not found error. None type of variable "session"

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

```
...
from flask_session import Session
import redis
...
app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET_KEY = '123456789012345678901234'
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
SESSION_REDIS = redis.from_url('localhost:6379')

app.config.from_object(__name__)

sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
...
# Should be available accross requests now
session['key'] = value
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Using `sess.init_app(app)` instead of `Session(app)` did the trick.